# Matlab: run program until condition is met

Tags: matlab, conditional-statements

I'm currently modelling the dynamics of an ice sheet. I therefore made a script that plots the volume of an ice sheet throughout time (in steps of 500 years). The volume increases rapidly at first, but the curve flattens later on as the volume does not change anymore and the ice sheet is in steady state... its shape is familiar like y=ln(x)... I thus have 2 output arrays, namely a) vol_time with the time in steps of 500 years and b) vol with the corresponding volume. Now, the program runs until a fixed time that I inserted (200 000 years) but I want to run the program only until this steady state is reached. So my question is: how can I make the program run only until the volume changes with only 0.002% per 500 years?

Thanks

Comment: I assume you have some `for` loop? Are you aware of `break` which allows you to exit the loop before the last iteration is reached? Please put some example code into your question demonstrating the structure of your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can ether wrap your ice-sheet thickness calculation in a while loop so the code performs the calculation until the 0.0002% condition is met or you loop through the whole 200.000 years.

Another option could be to add a if check end the end of your ice-sheet thickness calculation and if you enter and then add `break` in the if, this way the loop terminate.

Comment: Not having enough rep to comment does not mean answer with your comment. Answers without code are not very useful.